# Ordenamento de Datas ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá, esse é minha primeira dúvida neste mundo do `R` e ainda não o domino por completo.
 Estou aprendendo essa maravilhosa linguagem e agora estou com sérios problemas  na plotagem de um gráfico usando o pacote `ggplot2`, os dados são datas  e elas não seguem a ordem natural de datas.

[image: gráfico]

Segue código

```
ggplot(tab.OpTT)+ 
geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v1, group = 1), fill = "black")+                                             
geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v2, group = 1), fill = "red")+
geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v3, group = 1), fill = "blue")+                       
labs(x = "Período de 05/02 á 18/02", y = "Chamadas criadas", title = "teste 
1")
```

Segue dados:

```
Dia;v3;v1;v2;v4;v5
19-jan;44;166;156;8,13;0,15
20-jan;32;74;86;11,65;0
21-jan;29;16;21;13,47;0
22-jan;77;163;104;1,56;0,22
23-jan;31;162;210;3,65;0,2
24-jan;49;179;161;2,39;0,13
25-jan;43;185;192;2,94;0,17
26-jan;29;157;172;4,48;0,15
27-jan;62;127;94;2,33;0,07
28-jan;55;25;41;3,41;0
29-jan;53;238;240;2,47;0,31
30-jan;60;222;222;2,45;0,21
31-jan;60;174;174;2,29;0,47
1-fev;39;166;188;3,69;0,22
2-fev;15;123;148;6,23;0,51
3-fev;12;103;107;8,02;0
4-fev;13;24;27;7,65;0
5-fev;36;221;198;2,89;0,18
6-fev;37;155;157;2,71;0,4
7-fev;25;151;165;4,18;0,25
8-fev;26;149;148;4,05;0,28
9-fev;20;147;153;5,47;0,15
```

Então , tentei diversas formas para corrigir, usando o pacote `lubridate`, porém queria colocar no formato disponível na tabela `DD-M` para não ocupar espaço no eixo X e o `lubridate` só trabalha com os padrão usando ano (`dd-mm-yyyy`). Também é percebido que há muitos dados no eixo x e seria bom mostrar apenas algumas amostras nesse eixo, mas usando o total dos dados referentes a variável `Dia` na construção do gráfico.

Fico grato pela qualquer ajuda que venha por vir.

obs. os dados `v4` e `v5` não são usados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minha sugestão é que as datas no R sejam sempre representadas no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`. Isto facilita demais o trabalho com o software na hora de trabalhar com este tipo de dado. Ele precisa entender os dias exatos com os quais tu está lidando para que os resultados exibidos sejam corretos.

Isto posto, vou criar uma coluna com dados de data no teu conjunto de dados:

```
library(lubridate)

tab.OpTT$Dia <- seq(ymd("2018-01-19"), ymd("2018-02-09"), by="days")
```

Com o R exige que eu coloque um ano na data, optei por usar 2018. Isto pode ser alterado depois de acordo com as tuas necessidades.

Agora é só adicionar a formatação de data ao gráfico que tu já tinha feito:

```
ggplot(tab.OpTT)+ 
  geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v1, group = 1), fill = "black")+                 
  geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v2, group = 1), fill = "red")+
  geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v3, group = 1), fill = "blue")+
  labs(x = "Período de 05/02 á 18/02", y = "Chamadas criadas", title = "teste 1") +
  scale_x_date(breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 day"), 
    date_labels="%d/%m", minor_breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia),
    max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 day")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que utilizei um número para me referir ao mês. É possível utilizar outra formatação para a data se eu alterar um argumento dentro de `scale_x_date`:

```
ggplot(tab.OpTT)+ 
  geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v1, group = 1), fill = "black")+                 
  geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v2, group = 1), fill = "red")+
  geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v3, group = 1), fill = "blue")+
  labs(x = "Período de 05/02 á 18/02", y = "Chamadas criadas", title = "teste 1") +
  scale_x_date(breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 day"), 
    date_labels="%d/%b", minor_breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia),
    max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 day")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enfim, as opções são várias. Caso as soluções que postei aqui não sejam ideais, eu recomendo que tu brinque com `scale_x_date` até achar algo que te agrade.

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado e vou analisar muito bem a sua resolução. Tópico fechado =)

Comment: Como complementação, o comando `tab.OpTT$Dia <- seq(ymd("2018-01-19"), ymd("2018-02-09"), by="days")` funciona bem para o exemplo pois são dias seguidos. Caso isso não seja aplicado, você pode transformá-los em `Date` com `tab.OpTT$Dia <- as.Date(tab.OpTT$Dia, format = "%d-%b")` (isso após os transformar em `character` `tab.OpTT$Dia <- as.character(tab.OpTT$Dia)`)

Comment: @RafaelCunha O `as.Date` precise do ano, como diz o Marcus Nunes. Podia fazer-se `as.Date(paste0(tab.OpTT$Dia, "-2018"), format = "%d-%b-%Y")`

Comment: @RuiBarradas ao rodar o comando `as.Date(tab.OpTT$Dia, format = "%d-%b")`, ele já inclui automaticamente o ano de 2018 aqui pra mim.

Comment: @RafaelCunha Tem razão, é a primeira vez que vejo isto. Também resulta com `as.Date("19-01", format = "%d-%m")`. A minha confusão deve vir de a página `?as.Date` só ter exemplos com o ano, e fiquei com a impressão que era obrigatório. Além disso, muitas vezes surgem perguntas **sem o dia** e esse sim, é obrigatório.

Comment: Olá novamente @RafaelCunha, estou com problemas em transformar o eixo X em mês/ano, usando o seu código como base, então fiz alterações para essa adaptação. Os limites ainda são os extremos da tabela `breaks=seq(min(dados$tempo), max(dados$tempo), by="1 month"` ,  as labels mudei `date_labels="%b/%y"` estilo mês/ano. Minha dúvida é o uso dos 
`by =" "`, eles são os parâmetros de escala?

Comment: @macchi o código base foi do Marcus, eu só indiquei uma nova forma de transformar sua variável `Dia` para o formato `Date`. Além do mais, acho que não entendi muito bem a sua nova dúvida.

Comment: Só queria mudar, invés de ser em uma progressão de dias,mas em mêses.

Comment: Consegui resolver: `dados$tempo <- seq(ymd("2017-02-01"), ymd("2018-02-01"), by="months")` no ggplot `scale_x_date(breaks=seq(min(dado$dia), max(dado$dia), by="1 months"),  date_labels="%b/%Y", minor_breaks=seq(min(dado$dia), max(dado$dia), by="1 months"))` . Com isso plot vai sair na escala de meses.