# Não cria a legenda no gráfico do ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá, estou aqui para expor um problema bem básico que está ocorrendo, não estou conseguindo plotar junto ao gráfico a legenda. Não vou falar muita coisa, apenas vou por o meu código e o print do gráfico para vocês analisarem.

```
library(lubridate)
library(gtable)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(extrafont)
library(data.table)
library(scales)
loadfonts(device="win")

tab.OpTT$Dia <- seq(ymd("2018-01-19"), ymd("2018-02-18"), by="days")


p1 <- ggplot(tab.OpTT)+
      geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v1))+
      geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v2), alpha = 0.7)+
      geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v3), alpha = 0.8)+
      labs( title= "TESTE", y="Chamadas", x = NULL)+
      scale_x_date(breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 day"),  date_labels="%d/%b", minor_breaks=seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 month"))+  
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 300)) +
      theme(
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
            panel.background = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = 0.5), 
            panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
            text = element_text(family="Simplon BP Light"),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),
            axis.title = element_text(color = "gray50", size = 14, family = "Simplon BP Light"),
            axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
            axis.ticks.length = unit(.25, "cm"),
            axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "gray50"),
            legend.position="bottom",
            legend.title = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
            legend.text = element_text(colour="gray50", size=10, face="bold", family = "Simplon BP Light" ),
            legend.box = "horizontal",
    scale_color_manual(values=c('#3D196D','#B18AE4','#490F49',guide=FALSE)),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "gray50", size = 14, face = "bold", family = "Simplon BP Light"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os Dados estão no post anterior que abri: 
[Ordenamento de Datas ggplot2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277500/ordenamento-de-datas-ggplot2)

Dados por dput, requisitado pelo  Rafael Cunha.

```
structure(list(Dia = structure(c(17550, 17551, 17552, 17553, 
17554, 17555, 17556, 17557, 17558, 17559, 17560, 17561, 17562, 
17563, 17564, 17565, 17566, 17567, 17568, 17569, 17570, 17571, 
17572, 17573, 17574, 17575, 17576, 17577, 17578, 17579, 17580
), class = "Date"), v3 = c(44L, 32L, 29L, 77L, 31L, 49L, 
43L, 29L, 62L, 55L, 53L, 60L, 60L, 39L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 36L, 37L, 
25L, 26L, 20L, 22L, 16L, 25L, 11L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 28L, 17L), 
v1 = c(166L, 74L, 16L, 163L, 162L, 179L, 185L, 157L, 
127L, 25L, 238L, 222L, 174L, 166L, 123L, 103L, 24L, 221L, 
155L, 151L, 149L, 147L, 93L, 34L, 93L, 42L, 168L, 148L, 162L, 
108L, 35L), v2 = c(156L, 86L, 21L, 104L, 210L, 161L, 
192L, 172L, 94L, 41L, 240L, 222L, 174L, 188L, 148L, 107L, 
27L, 198L, 157L, 165L, 148L, 153L, 91L, 40L, 84L, 56L, 158L, 
149L, 167L, 105L, 53L), v4 = c(8.13, 11.65, 13.47, 1.56, 
3.65, 2.39, 2.94, 4.48, 2.33, 3.41, 2.47, 2.45, 2.29, 3.69, 
6.23, 8.02, 7.65, 2.89, 2.71, 4.18, 4.05, 5.47, 4.98, 7.06, 
4.8, 11.08, 5.65, 5.34, 5.02, 4.61, 7.8), v5 = c(0.15, 0, 
0, 0.22, 0.2, 0.13, 0.17, 0.15, 0.07, 0, 0.31, 0.21, 0.47, 
0.22, 0.51, 0, 0, 0.18, 0.4, 0.25, 0.28, 0.15, 0.06, 0, 0.17, 
0.03, 0.2, 0.32, 0.29, 0.01, 0)), .Names = c("Dia", "v3", 
"v1", "v2", "v4", "v5"), row.names = c(NA, -31L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Não é possível reproduzir seu problema, mesmo pegando seus dados no seu post anterior. Não temos como saber qual a é variável `legenda` que é utilizada aqui `geom_area(aes(x = Dia, y = v1, group = legenda, fill = legenda))+`. Sugiro editar sua pergunta adicionando uma parte do banco de dados que você está utilizando (comando `dput`).

Comment: Rafael cunha, alterei o código como estava antes. Receio não conhecer esse comando dput, mas o banco só possui mesmo as 6 variáveis (Dia,v1,v2,v3,v4 e v5) do outro post. O `legenda` eu vi em tutoriais, tentei reproduzir...

Comment: Aparece algum erro pra você ao rodar o _script_?

Comment: Aparece: `Error in (function (el, elname)  : 
  Element line must be a element_line object`.  Mas o código plota o grafico certo, porém sem a legenda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Primeiro adicionei a opção `fill = "v?"` dentro de cada `aes` das `geom_area` (referentes a cada variável de interesse). Removi a seguinte linha do seu código

`scale_color_manual(values=c('#3D196D','#B18AE4','#490F49',guide=FALSE))`

já que ela servia para a criação da legenda e, inclui,

`scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("v1" = "#3D196D", "v2" = "#B18AE4", "v3" = "#490F49"))`

do lado de fora da função `theme`. Segue imagem gerada:

[image: Imgur]

e código final:

```
ggplot(tab.OpTT, aes(x = Dia)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = v1, fill = "v1")) +
  geom_area(aes(y = v2, fill = "v2"), alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_area(aes(y = v3, fill = "v3"), alpha = 0.8) +
  labs(title = "TESTE", y = "Chamadas") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by="1 day"),
           date_labels = "%d/%b", minor_breaks = seq(min(tab.OpTT$Dia), max(tab.OpTT$Dia), by = "1 month")) +  
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 300)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("v1" = "#3D196D", "v2" = "#B18AE4", "v3" = "#490F49")) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
    panel.background = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = 0.5), 
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(family="Simplon BP Light"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.title = element_text(color = "gray50", size = 14, family = "Simplon BP Light"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(.25, "cm"),
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour = "gray50"),
    legend.position="bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(colour="gray50", size=10, face="bold", family = "Simplon BP Light" ),
    legend.box = "horizontal",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "gray50", size = 14, face = "bold", family = "Simplon BP Light"))
```

Comment: Realmente resolveu, agradeço novamente @Rafael Cunha =) .

Answer (score 0):

Já tive esse problema, vamos ver se a minha solução se aplica a você: tente botar a linha *labs* por último.

```
labs( title= "TESTE", y="Chamadas", x = NULL)
```

Comment: Não funcionou amigo, mas obrigado.